# Notifications with several lines of information

Tags: android, notification

I'm making an application that checks for wind speed and direction on several locations and made notification that shows when a location has enough wind.

The information the notification should hold is variable from one location :
Oslo (8 m/s Direction West)

to several places :
Oslo (8 m/s Direction: West)
Bergen (9 m/s Direction: East)
Bergen (9 m/s Direction: East)
Bergen (9 m/s Direction: East)

The notification style is InboxStyle, but users comment that the notification provides a lot of information and is quite cluttered. What would be the the best approach to this? Maybe direct them to the app?

Comment: You could reduce the information in the brackets to a graphical arrow with a number in it to show wind speed and direction. That might already reduce the clutter enough. If that is an option in your environment. Or even an ASCII version like `«=9=<` (might not be intuitive enough for your audience)

Comment: Sould like a good idea. I'm also considering a solution that will only show notification for 5 user selected spots. I could  use location aware notifications but that would increase the battery use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dukes had a good suggestion.  I had seen something like that in the various weather apps too.  See below.  Seems like a good idea and should be easily recognizable.  [image]

Comment: I really liked the design of your "location eather view". What is the other screen ? And may i ask how you handle notifications ? If you have ?

Comment: Oh the other screen was just their settings info.  Derek has a good point below about how Gmail handles it if they wish to see more info.  One of the ways you could try as well would be just show the bare minimum, say the little wind icon in one direction with the number next to it.  Then maybe to the right, you have the chevron/arrow and if the user clicks that, it slides over and shows the very detailed view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've tried this already but consider using expandable notifications. Show a maximum 4 pieces of information in there followed by "..." To show the user they must click the notification to view more information.

This design pattern is used by gmail and many others and I'd consider it to be good ux. Honestly if you can present the more complex info better inside your app do it.